# Bloc library state not rebuilding

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: MultiBlocListener(
    listeners: [
      BlocListener<QuestionholderBloc, QuestionholderState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is NoQuestions) {
            _dbbloc.add(GetQuestions());
          } else if (state is HasQuestions) {
            _statusbloc.add(GetQuestion());
          }
        },
      ),
      BlocListener<DatabaseBloc, DatabaseState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is Loaded) {
            _statusbloc.add(SetQuestions(questionsToSet: state.questions));
          }
        },
      ),
    ],
    child: BlocBuilder<QuestionholderBloc, QuestionholderState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is QuestionLoaded) {
          return QuestionWidget(question: state.question);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

I have a button on the QuestionWidget that triggers the getQuestion event.
Initially, everything works fine but the QuestionWidget doesn't rebuild with the new value when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the bloc but I was passing the same question over and over again. Now it works.